# How can I force dnf in Fedora 35 to download new GPG keys?

Tags: linux, fedora, gnupg, dnf, keybase

I am suddenly unable to update Keybase through dnf. I am getting the following error:

```
Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Upgrade  1 Package

Total size: 159 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
[SKIPPED] keybase-5.9.0.20211217212642.29bfd9d39f-1.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded
keybase                                         37 kB/s | 6.8 kB     00:00    
GPG key at https://keybase.io/docs/server_security/code_signing_key.asc (0x656D16C7) is already installed
The GPG keys listed for the "keybase" repository are already installed but they are not correct for this package.
Check that the correct key URLs are configured for this repository.. Failing package is: keybase-5.9.0.20211217212642.29bfd9d39f-1.x86_64
GPG Keys are configured as: https://keybase.io/docs/server_security/code_signing_key.asc
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: GPG check FAILED
```

The message says that the GPG keys for the keybase repo are already installed. But when I attempt to list them with

> $ gpg --list-secret-keys

I get nothing.

What is the correct way to force dnf to download the GPG keys again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future searches: A new version of keybase was released with an explicit suggestion to replace the existing key:

> ```sh
> rpm -e gpg-pubkey-656d16c7
> dnf update keybase
> ```

https://github.com/keybase/client/releases/tag/v5.9.1

(See also https://github.com/keybase/client/issues/24637 for the context)